# Android Streaming Video Recognition using AWS REKOGNITION

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-rekognition

I am working on a creating an application that will capture video from android device. Send this device to AWS Rekognition for object detection and classification and show results back to user.

I want to know how will I integrate Android live Video with kinesis video stream and show results of objects back to user.

Can I have some reference architecture for this solution.